# Most efficient way to store and sort words by length?

Tags: java

Since many words might have the same length, an insertion operation to a certain database can be costly.

I saw the following suggestions for storing and sorting words by length. Which is the most efficient?

1. Key: length of word, Value: Set of all words with that length.
   Using HashMap:
   [Sorting all words in a file by length, in one read. (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244627/sorting-all-words-in-a-file-by-length-in-one-read-java)
2. Using Guava's MultiMap:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/4244798/2653179
3. TreeMap? Or storing the words in an ArrayList, writing compare function, then using Collections.sort:
   [Java: Sort a list of words by length, then by alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885656/java-sort-a-list-of-words-by-length-then-by-alphabetical-order)

Or other suggestions?

Comment: It very much depends on the scenario. Could you explain what you mean with "Since many words might have the same length, an insertion operation to a certain database can be costly"? How can grouping words by length affect db insertion?

Comment: A `trie` is an option?

Comment: After you have sorted by length, what do you plan to do with the data?  Does it matter how long it takes to retrieve a specific word or do you just want to list all the words with the same length?

Comment: @AndreyChaschev, The words aren't grouped by length when inserting. Insertion can be O(N).

Comment: @nachokk, sure, any efficient method would help. :)

Comment: @JustinKSU, just to output them by length order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Most efficient way to store and sort words by length?

`Map<Integer, List<String>>` - map where the key is the word length and the value is a list with words

Comment: This is effective only for write operations, which is O(1). If you want to find whether a word is in the database it is O(n) where n is word length, so  it can be pretty expensive for words with length around 6 (there are many such words). But if you care only about write operation cost this looks to be optimal.

Comment: @ViktorK. Doesn't the efficiency depend on the implementation of Map and List?

Comment: Thanks, which implementation of Map and List would you recommend? HashMap and ArrayList?

Comment: @user2653179 Yes. They should do the job.

Comment: @JustinKSU yes of course. My assumption here is that we have a HashMap and LinkedList (or ArrayList)) because Adam was focusing on write(storing) efficiency. This is not optimal only for storing. PRobably the best would be to use Set<String> instead of List<String as a value type of the Map. In this case the read operation would also be O(1) in most cases (using HashMap or LinkedHashMap if order is important).

Answer (score 2):

With using Guava you could create a multimap with keys sorted by a length:

```
TreeMultimap<Integer, String> map = TreeMultimap.create();

//as Java's map 
NavigableMap<Integer, Collection<String>> asMap = map.asMap();
```

Adding items:

```
for (String word : new String[]{"cd", "efg", "k", "a", "b", "ab"}) {
    map.put(word.length(), word);
}

System.out.println("words: " + map);
```

Prints:

```
words: {1=[a, b, k], 2=[ab, cd], 3=[efg]}
```